# NDSolve error: what does "It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form" mean?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a set of partial differential equations numerically:

```
NDSolve[
 D[f[x, y], x, x]^2 + D[g[x, y], x, x]^2 + D[f[x, y], x, y]^2 == 0 && 
 D[f[x, y], y, y]^2 + D[g[x, y], y, y]^2 + D[f[x, y], x, y]^2 == 0 &&
 f[x, 0] == 0 && g[x, 0] == 0 && 1 == (D[f[x, q], q] /. q -> 0) && 
 1 == (D[g[x, q], q] /. q -> 0) && 1 == (D[f[x, 0], x]) && 1 == (D[g[x, 0], x])
 ,{f, g}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Mathematica 12 returns the following error message:
[image]

what does this error message mean? How can I fix the input?

Comment: What does this model describe?

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is a dummy minimal input example that reproduces the same Mathematica error as my actual PDE of interest, which would not fit onto the page.

Comment: It is necessary to bring the system to a quasilinear form.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hmm, now I'm confused about the statement "A PDE which is neither linear nor quasi-linear is said to be nonlinear." from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html . How can we bring a nonlinear PDE into quasi-linear form? Since studying a nonlinear one is kind of the objective...

Comment: Usually differentiated equations by `x` or `y` and introduce new variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the three dots in front of the error message

[image]

and follow the link to the reference page you will find some information on this error message.

Next, you have to bring your PDE into the coefficient form:

$$ \nabla \cdot (-c(t,X,u,\nabla _Xu) \nabla u-\alpha (t,X,u,\nabla _Xu) u $$
$$ + \gamma (t,X,u,\nabla _Xu)) + \beta (t,X,u,\nabla _Xu)\cdot \nabla u+a(t,X,u,\nabla _Xu) u$$ $$ - f(t,X,u,\nabla _Xu)=0.$$

Details are [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1484968070). And you have to get your equation into that form otherwise you are out of FEM luck. Also see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195481/18437).