# FEM: Why are the numerical solutions of field equations with D and Inactive[Div] and Inactive[Grad] different?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 12.1.1 or earlier - Fixed in Version: 12.2.0**

Suppose you have the DE

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left(
c(x) \left[\frac{d}{dx}u(x)\right]
\right) + n(x) = 0
$$

and you want to solve for $u(x)$ with some BCs with given $c(x)$ and $n(x)$. I thought that solving this with the formulations

```
de1 = D[c[x]*D[u[x], x], x] + n[x];
de2 = Inactive[Div][c[x]*Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + n[x];
```

which at least in a symbolic form are the same in 1D

```
de1 == Activate@de2
```

> True

would yield the same results. But no no no! I do not get the same results, see below, I do not understand why. Can you help me out? I am working with Mathematica 12.0.0.0

Let's define some region boundaries for $x$ through `xReg`, impose some BCs with `uBC`, define $c$ and $n$, and finally set up a solver `usol` for given `de`.

```
xReg = {-3, 10};
uBC = {0, 7};
c[x_] := (5 + Sin[x])*(7 + 2*Cos[x]);
n[x_] := 50*Sin[x];
bc = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == uBC[[1]], x == xReg[[1]]],
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == uBC[[2]], x == xReg[[2]]]
   };
usol[de_] := 
  NDSolveValue[{de == 0, bc}, u, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}];
```

In Mathematica 12.0.0.0 I get the following **different** results after solving `de1` and `de2`

```
u1 = usol[de1];
u2 = usol[de2];
Plot[{u1[x], u2[x]}, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"D", "Inactive - Div - Grad"}]
```

[image]

I simply do not understand **why**. I have read parts of [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) (Formal Partial Differential Equations), but the use of `Inactive` is somehow unclear to me in this example. In terms of a naive observation, the solution `u1` obtained with `D` seems to be right, which yiels `n1` in the figure below, i.e., `n1` $\approx$ `-n`. `n2`, computed from `u2` with `Inactive` does not show good results (yellow and green curves corresponding to `n2` and `n22` based on `u2` are on top of each other).

```
n1 = D[c[x]*D[u1[x], x], x];
n2 = Div[c[x]*Grad[u2[x], {x}], {x}];
n22 = D[c[x]*D[u2[x], x], x];
Plot[{n1, n2, n22, -n[x]}, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n1", "n2", "n22", "-n"}]
```

[image]

Further questions:

1. Is this solved in newer Mathematica versions?
2. Does the internal FEM do something weird to the DE? If yes, then I am concerned that the solution of user21 in [my other old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195477/how-do-i-use-the-new-nonlinear-finite-element-in-mathematica-12-for-this-equatio) might be questionable due to the usage of `Inactive` with `Div` and `Grad` in the provided nonlinear 1D example.

Comment: The same output appears in 12.1.1.  I don't know too much about this, but is there an implicit `NeumannValue[0,pred]` on the boundary in the FEM method?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I impose BCs at both ends such that no NeumannValue could be active. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: You may want to take a look at @user21's answer here [225841](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/61809).  It provides a function to parse out the inactive form of the PDE that will be available in the upcoming release.  There definitely are some peculiarities with 1d problems and I don't know if the function works on them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like a parsing bug to me. Changing the equation to a more formal form fixes the problem:

```
de2fixed = Inactive[Div][{{c[x]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + n[x]
```

As you can see, I've changed `c[x]*` to `{{c[x]}}.`.

Tested in *v12.1.1*.

Comment: Thanks for you help to track this down.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like being very formal is a good practice with the FEM. I should wear a suit next time I work with it :D

Answer (score 11):

**Bug fixed in Version: 12.2.0**

Yes, unfortunately a parser bug. I apologize for the trouble this causes. My bad. I have put in a fix for review such that this will be eliminated in 12.2.

The issue comes up because in parsing rule

```
Inactive[Div][Times[ c_, Inactive[Grad][dvar_]]]
```

it was required that c be a number. That is too strict, it needs to be a scalar.

Suggested workarounds:

This is probably the best workaround as the `{{c[x]}}`

```
de2 = Inactive[Div][{{c[x]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + n[x];
```

As this goes down another route (it uses Dot)

Other alternatives are

```
de2 = Inactive[Div][
    Inactive[Dot][c[x], Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}]], {x}] + n[x];
```

or

```
ClearAll[c]
c[x_] := Evaluate[(5 + Sin[x])*(7 + 2*Cos[x]) // Expand];
```

Once again, sorry for the trouble. If you have suggestions on how the mentioned tutorial section can be improved, please let me know.

Your other question is not affected by this. If you are concerned you can wrap the coefficient in {{}}. like so:

```
Omega = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
c[x_] := x^2 + 3;
r[x_] := Sin@x;
eq[p_] := 
 Inactive[Div][{{(c[x]*D[u[x], x]^(p - 1))}}.Inactive[Grad][
     u[x], {x}], {x}] == r[x]
bc = DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! No worries about the trouble. We all contribute to the improvement :D

Answer (score 10):

## Update to Include @xzczd Fix

I do not have great familiarity with @user21's workflow that I mentioned in the comment [225841](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/61809), but, if you follow it, then you will see that `de2` dropped $(sin(x)+5)$ term of the non-linear diffusion coefficient to the parsed equations that probably is not intended. If we apply @xzczd's fix, the `Inactive` PDEs match.

## @user21's Function to Parse Equations to Inactive Forms

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
zeroCoefficientQ[c_] := Union[N[Flatten[c]]] === {0.}
ClearAll[GetInactivePDE]
GetInactivePDE[pdec_PDECoefficientData, vd_] := 
 Module[{lif, sif, dif, mif, hasTimeQ, tvar, vars, depVars, neqn, 
   nspace, dep, load, dload, diff, cconv, conv, react, 
   pde}, {lif, sif, dif, mif} = pdec["All"];
  tvar = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "Time"];
  If[tvar === None || tvar === {}, hasTimeQ = False;
   tvar = Sequence[];, hasTimeQ = True;];
  vars = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "Space"];
  depVars = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "DependentVariables"];
  neqn = Length[depVars];
  nspace = Length[vars];
  dep = (# @@ Join[{tvar}, vars]) & /@ depVars;
  {load, dload} = lif;
  {diff, cconv, conv, react} = sif;
  load = load[[All, 1]];
  dload = dload[[All, 1, All, 1]];
  conv = conv[[All, All, 1, All]];
  cconv = cconv[[All, All, All, 1]];
  pde = If[hasTimeQ, 
    mif[[1]].D[dep, {tvar, 2}] + dif[[1]].D[dep, tvar], 
    ConstantArray[0, {Length[dep]}]];
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[diff], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[Inactive[
          Div][-diff[[r, c]].Inactive[Grad][dep[[c]], vars], 
         vars], {r, neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[cconv], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[Inactive[Div][-cconv[[r, c]]*dep[[c]], vars], {r, 
         neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[dload], 
   pde += (Inactive[Div][#, vars] & /@ dload);];
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[conv], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[conv[[r, c]].Inactive[Grad][dep[[c]], vars], {r, 
         neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  pde += react.dep;
  pde -= load;
  pde]
(* From Vitaliy Kaurov for nice display of operators *)
pdConv[f_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> 
    Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
     Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
        Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]
```

## Initial OP Data and @xzczd's Fix

```
de1 = D[c[x]*D[u[x], x], x] + n[x];
de2 = Inactive[Div][c[x]*Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + n[x];
de2fixed = 
  Inactive[Div][{{c[x]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + n[x];
de1 == Activate@de2
xReg = {-3, 10};
uBC = {0, 7};
c[x_] := (5 + Sin[x])*(7 + 2*Cos[x]);
n[x_] := 50*Sin[x];
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == uBC[[1]], x == xReg[[1]]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == uBC[[2]], x == xReg[[2]]]};
usol[de_] := NDSolveValue[{de == 0, bc}, u, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}];
u1 = usol[de1];
u2 = usol[de2];
u3 = usol[de2fixed];
Plot[{u1[x], u2[x], u3[x]}, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"D", "Inactive - Div - Grad", "Fixed"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Directive[Green, Dashed], 
   Directive[Opacity[0.25], Thick, Blue]}]
```

[image: Comparison Plot]

There is now good overlap for `de1` and `de2fixed`.

## Workflow To Parse Equations

```
op = de1;
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0, bc}, 
   u, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}];
femd = state["FiniteElementData"];
vd = state["VariableData"];
pdec = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
pde1 = GetInactivePDE[pdec, vd];

op = de2;
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0, bc}, 
   u, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}];
femd = state["FiniteElementData"];
vd = state["VariableData"];
pdec = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
pde2 = GetInactivePDE[pdec, vd];

op = de2fixed;
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0, bc}, 
   u, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}];
femd = state["FiniteElementData"];
vd = state["VariableData"];
pdec = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
pde3 = GetInactivePDE[pdec, vd];

pde1 // pdConv
pde2 // pdConv
pde3 // pdConv
```

[image: Parsed Equations]

Presuming the parsing works, it appears the @xzczd's fix has harmonized the equations.

Comment: "it appears that de1 has introduced a convective term into the div operator. " It doesn't seem to be. `Sin[x]+5`, which is part of `c[x]`, is missing in 2nd case. Perhaps a mistake in pattern matching?

Comment: @xzczd Good catch!  I will have a look.  This question inspired me to try out @user21's workflow of `GetInactivePDE`.  I probably got happy feet and was too quick to answer without a proper thorough review.  I will update my answer.  Do you mind if include `de2fixed` in my revision?

Comment: Feel free to include :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thanks and updated!

Comment: Thanks for you help to track this down.

Comment: Thank you very much for also providing the conparison between the parsed equations!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a misconception overall.

Both equations a essentially the very same, because

```
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(z[x]\)\)

Derivative[1][z][x]
```

[image]

are equivalent and more suitable rewriting valid in Mathematica too.

There is a problem to estimate what is actually there because the input and the output are generally different. Just the Activate/Inactivate pairing can be controlled.

Following the documentation of [Activate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) two Inactivate compensate for two Activates:

[image: copy from the documentation for Activate]

So what actually happens and is responsible for the difference in the result is that during the integration of the differential equation in `NDSolveValue` the second level of the Inactive pair is still not activated. It is integrated as a constant and gives rise to the higher variation in function values of the result.

It is necessary despite the fact that the representation in the Mathematica notebook to apply the second Activate first and then NDSolveValue.

The given example shows that there is even a difference if the Inactivate is applied to two consecutive differentiation and integration operators.

The comparison built-on just judges the formal identity between both sides, not the activation or inactivation. It is meaningless for those considerations.

Meaning arises from the application. That is at the first time done in the question if the NDSolveValue is applied. In addition, it is possible to activate both operation differentiation and integration separately and the equation in a whole.

Think of the result of the operation of Inactive on a cascaded set of D and Integrate built-ins as it operates on each separately. To inactive both only one Inactivate suffices.

```
u1 = usol[de1];
u2 = usol[Activate@Activate@de2];
Plot[{u1[x], u2[x]}, {x, xReg[[1]], xReg[[2]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"D", "Inactive - Div - Grad"}]
```

[image: Plot of u1 and u2 after double Activate on u2]

Comment: The plot shown does not match the plot generated with the code given. Note that `usol[Activate@de2] == usol[Activate@Activate@de2]` gives `True`. The point of the question is the observation that `usol[de2]` should be roughly equal to `usol[de1]` which in 12.1.1 is not that case. That is a bug and it's fixed in 12.2.