# FEM: Parsing error for ∂ in NDSolveValue? NDSolveValue: No derivatives of dependent variables

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I came across an error/inconsistency when using inactive `∂` operators in `NDSolveValue`, which could be a parsing error as well as suggested by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226647 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226658

I took the example from `Poisson’s Equation with Neumann Values` from the [off. docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601) without the Neumann BC

```
Ω = 
  ImplicitRegion[! ((x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 <= 3^2), {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 
     10}}];
op = -Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y], {x, y}] - 20
Subscript[Γ, D] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && 8 <= y <= 10];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
Plot3D[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

which nicely gives out

[image: Working outout]

However, when I rewrite the Laplace operator with `∂` NDSolveValue fails

```
opD = -(Inactive[D][u[x, y], {x, 2}] + 
     Inactive[D][u[x, y], {y, 2}]) - 20
ufun = NDSolveValue[{opD == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

[image: Failed output]

As a sanity check, activating the operator first works:

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Activate[opD] == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]},  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

Since I'll currently rely on many formulations of my PDEs with `∂`s and need Neumann BCs, can somebody help me out here what to do or am I missing something?

Comment: Without `Inactive` everything works fine!

Comment: Please don't add [tag:bugs] tag to the question until the community or WRI confirms it. Then, as mentioned in the linked post (don't miss those comments! ), this is not a bug, it's simply because `Inactive[D]` isn't supported by `NDSolve` at the moment.

Comment: > `Inactive[D]` isn't supported by `NDSolve` at the moment.
That explains it of course. Thanks.